# log4net does not create any log files

Tags: log4net

I am trying to implement logger with Log4net. I have done all the configuration that was documented but it does not create any messages also it does not even create a log file as well. I made sure the directory specified has user 'EVERYONE' full permissions.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>

<appSettings>
            <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".properties" mimeType="text/plain" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>

  <log4net>

    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender"  type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">

      <file value="C:\\Users\\raviteja\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\logs" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />

      <rollingStyle value="Date" />


      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

my Global.asax file has following lines

```
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.Ge‌​tCurrentMethod().Dec‌​laringType);
        log.Debug("This is a DEBUG level message. Typically your most VERBOSE level.");
}
```

and My page has following code to test

```
private static readonly log4net.ILog log =  LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    log.Debug(" log file created and tested ");

    log.Debug(DateTime.Now + " - Page Load");
}
```

The logs folder specified in the web.config section EVERYONE has full permissions to the folder. I can not seem to think any other reason why the log4net is not able to create log files.

Do you guys see anything that i am missing ?

Comment: What does `LogManager.GetRepository().Configured` return when called afer configuration? If `true`, then check the log4net debug output by piping it to a file or via `LogManager.GetRepository().ConfigurationMessages.Cast<LogLog>()`

Comment: I think that was it. `LogManager.GetRepository().Configured ` is true but it was throwing unable to acquire lock error.       I was pointing to a folder instead of a file `<file value="C:\\Users\\raviteja\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\logs" /> ` this was changed to       `<file value="C:\\Users\\raviteja\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\logs\log.txt" />` and it is working now.  @stuartd, thanks for your suggestion.